# Comportamiento Query SQLServer

Tags: sql-server

Intento crear una query para obtener un resultado con el cual intentaré sacar unas estadísticas, pero no entiendo donde está el fallo que hace que no saque bien la información.

Con un ejemplo concreto, la consulta sería:

```
select CE_CODCEN as INSTALACION,
        count(M.IN_EXPEDIENTE) as HOMES, 
        count(F.IN_EXPEDIENTE) as MULLERES 
from cvcentros C,CVINSTAN M, CVINSTAN F 
where M.IN_EXPEDIENTE in(select in_expediente from cvinstan where in_Sexo='M' and in_plaza='150001' and in_ano='2019') 
    and F.IN_EXPEDIENTE in(select in_expediente from cvinstan where in_Sexo='F' and in_plaza='150001' and in_ano='2019') 
group by CE_CODCEN 
order by CE_CODCEN
```

Obteniendo lo siguiente como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que es un resultado erróneo, ya que para la instalación 150001 el resultado debería ser 28 y 23. Extrayendo las subconsultas me sale bien el resultado:

```
select count(in_expediente) from cvinstan where in_Sexo='M' and in_plaza='150001' and in_ano='2019'

select count(in_expediente) from cvinstan where in_Sexo='F' and in_plaza='150001' and in_ano='2019'
```

No comprendo donde está el error en la query principal que hace que imprima estos datos.

ACTUALIZACION Y ACLARACION:

Tenemos dos tablas,CVCENTROS Y CVINSTAN, cada registro en CVINSTAN tiene un campo sexo y un campo que se relaciona con CE_CODCEN de CVCENTROS, lo que se intenta es conocer el nº de solicitantes de cada uno de los sexos para cada fila de CE_CODCEN.
Dispuestos de esa manera: INSTALACION-HOMBRES-MUJERES-OTRO

Comment: Estas haciendo un producto cartesiano, no hay una condicion de join, por eso te da cualquier cosa.

Comment: Ademas, salvo que tengas mas de dos sexos en la tabla cvinstan, no tiene ningun sentido la clausula IN, y tampoco poner dos veces la tabla...

Comment: Para poder corregir tu query, necesitariamos saber como se unen esas dos tablas,

Comment: @gbianchi Hay tres opciones para el sexo, por eso la cláusula, en cuanto a la unión, sería en que en la tabla CVINSTAN tiene un campo, PLAZA que correspondería al campo CODCEN de CVCENTROS. Sigo necesitando declarar la tabla dos veces al tener 3 opciones en el campo sexo?

Comment: no. Eso se va a solucionar con un case en el select. Tu where no va a buscar a una tabla en particular. Toda tu query, traducida al español, no esta haciendo lo que vos pensas, si no que mezcla todas las tablas, filtra algunas cosas y despues suma todo, varias veces. Por favor aclara todo en la pregunta para poder darte una respuesta

Comment: @gbianchi he añadido un apartado "ACTUALIZACION Y ACLARACION" explicando lo que se busca más concretamente, entiendo que en un principio esté mal explicado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al hacer:

```
from cvcentros C,CVINSTAN M, CVINSTAN F
```

Y no poner una condicion de join, implicitamente en el from (de la forma join on) o en el where (igualando los campos que unen las tablas) se produce un producto cartesiano.
Esto quiere decir que se unen todos los registros de cada tabla entre si.

Por lo tanto, si la tabla C tuviera 10 registros, y la tabla M 3, el resultado darian 30 registros.

Ademas: suponer que esto:

```
count(M.IN_EXPEDIENTE) as HOMES,
```

Va a contar solo los hombres, es un error. La tabla M no esta filtrada de ninguna manera (lo podrias haber hecho en el from, trayendo de esa tabla solo los registros que querias), pero al traerla completa, y solo poniendo el registro en el where, no soluciona el query de la forma que vos pensas.

Para solucionar el query tenemos que hacer lo siguiente.

```
select CE_CODCEN as INSTALACION,
    sum(case m.in_sexo
                when 'M' then 1
                else 0) as HOMES,
    sum(case m.in_sexo
                when 'F' then 1
                else 0) as MULLERES 
from cvcentros C left join CVINSTAN M on C.CE_CODCEN = M.CE_CODCEN 
where M.in_plaza = '150001' and m.in_ano = '2019'
group by CE_CODCEN 
order by CE_CODCEN
```

---

Notas:

- Es raro que el campo in_ano sea un varchar. no deberia ser un número?
- Uso un left join porque supongo que siempre queres traer todos los registros de cvcentros aunque no haya relacion con los de cvinstan. esto con un join comun tambien funcionaria.
- Uso un sum, porque por cada fila devuelvo 1 o 0 dependiendo si la fila me sirve o no, y como la agrupacion es lo ultimo que se hace, es la forma de contar las filas.